# bundler does not vendor/bundle :git source gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bundler

I'm using Bundler version 1.3.5 and Ruby 2.0.0-rc2.

When I use the command bundle install --deployment on my production server all my gems are copied to vendor/bundle, except for the one that has a :git source in the Gemfile.

I don't get any errors and the gem is listed and even downloaded when running the command, but it's not in the vendor/bundle folder.

All resources I've found on this are related to out-dated versions of Bundler which did not have this feature. Why is this happening on 1.3.5, though?

Answer (score 0):

Your "git" gem is stored and loaded from the cache directory. I think it's an implementation detail.

I've found the following note in the [documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html):

> While installing gems, Bundler will check vendor/cache and then your
>   system's gems. If a gem isn't cached or installed, Bundler will try to
>   install it from the sources you have declared in your Gemfile.

So the gem will be downloaded from git into `vendor/cache`, then bundler is going to install it, but it's already in the `vendor/cache`. So that is probably the reason, why you can't find it in the `vendor/bundle` directory.